# Detect zoom in/out scrollviewer uwp

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Ive been looking for a while to know how to detect when a zoom in/out takes place in a scrollviewer to update a text I have on the view using the zoom factor property.

I cant find an event on the xaml I can bind/attach and communicate my view model of the change. This has to work on the desktop version and for the surface pro version in a uwp project. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
sv.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(ScrollViewer.ZoomFactorProperty, (s, e) =>
{
    // your stuff.
});
```

Comment: amazing! Thanks @Jessica